# Não consigo acessar o controller da rota no Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-rotas

Não consigo acessar o controller do Laravel quando uso:

```
Route::controller('categorias', 'CategoryController');
```

Ele dá o seguinte erro:

> InvalidArgumentException Attribute [controller] does not exist.

Entretanto se eu fizer um outro tipo de rota:

`Route::get('/about', 'CategoryController@store');` /**(aqui ele vai normalmente)**/

Qual seria o problema?

Comment: Dependendo da versão pode utilizar o `Route::resource('name', '<controller>')` https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: Isso ajudou, mas como poderia passar apenas um controller na route e nele conseguir identificar os tipos de requisições HTTP (get, post, put, delete, options), digo, definindo no próprio Controller.

Comment: Teria como dar um exemplo?

Comment: Acredito que você esteja falando disso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505875/laravel-routeresource-vs-routecontroller